# Binding code-behind property of a wpf UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I am trying to create a Wpf UserControl with a variable number of buttons.
In the code behind `public string[] MenuItems { get; set; }` contains the Text (Content) of the buttons, so every item in the array should correspond to one button.

I tried:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Controls.MenuButtons"
             xmlns:m="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False"
               Background="{StaticResource ControlBackground}"
               DockPanel.Dock="Top"
               Height="35"
               Margin="5,0,0,0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding}"
                            Style="{StaticResource MenuButton}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Using the control in a window like this:

```
<c:MenuButtons MenuItems="..."></c:MenuButtons>
```

Gives the error:
The member "MenuItems" is not recognized or is not accessible.
MenuItems is sometimes recognized in xaml intellisense, sometimes not.
The window has iself as datacontext:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Comment: can you share how are you defining the MenuItems property ?

Comment: @nit, just: `public string[] MenuItems { get; set; }` although I also tried adding a dependency property `public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MenuItems", typeof(string), typeof(MenuButtons), new PropertyMetadata(""));`

Comment: type of menuitems is not correct in your dependancy property registeration...

Comment: can you show some more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MenuItems` property should be a `DependancyProperty` in order to use it as Binding Target.

The type should be string[] not string.

```
static readonly DependencyProperty MenuItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MenuItems", typeof(string[]), typeof(MenuButtons), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: That propably was a typo. When I use MenuItems="{StaticResource days}" at runtime one button is displayed instead if intended 3 but at least thats a start. Still the error "not recognized or is not accessible" is displayed and I cannot view the window in design time.